# opening file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to read float samples saved in text file. The file appears to be empty, even though it's filled with data. What might be the cause?

```
QFile file;;
QDir path;
path.setPath("home/kokos/Pobrane/wavreader/libsndfile-1.0.26/examples/ex2/qt_project/rainfilter");
file.setFileName(path.path() + "/samples.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QDataStream in(&file);
while(in.atEnd() == false)
{
    in >> samplesBuffer[counter];
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Show us a full program we can test.  Right now we can't even see what `samplesBuffer` is.

Comment: You're attempting to read the file without checking if it's even open...

Comment: Add a slash to the beginning of path, like this "/home/kokos/..."

Answer (score 5):

I can't write comments, but I work with qt long time.
Are u sure that file is open? You must open file that:

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    //some method
}
```

I think that u need check path name